# Why do databases create operating system users on Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, mongodb, postgresql

I opened my /etc/passwd file only to find that all databases i have installed have created a user during their installation. Why do databases when installed (at least on Linux) create a user? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Please list database names from /etc/passwd. AFAIK only database software installation can create user accounts like mysql, postgres or mongod; but these accounts are for each software installation and not for each created database.

Comment: Yes i wasn't clear with the terminology.. there is a user for each software installation of a dbms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is dangerous to run software as `root`, because any security breach would give the attacker control over the machine. Also, bugs in the software could cause more damage.

For that reason, software only runs as `root` when that is absolutely required. With databases, there is no such requirement.

Therefore, the installation packages will normally create an operating system user that is used to run the database server processes. If there is also a database user of the same name, that is mostly by accident, or because it seemed like a natural choice.

Comment: Thanks ! But why aren't those processes run with the owner being me a non root user with sudo privileges? Isn't that safe as well ? Thank you a again for your answer !

Comment: You can run these processes as any user. Note that we are talking about the database *server* processes here, so it is independent of the user running the client software. It is just customary to run the PostgreSQL processes as a `postgres` user.